# How to reload the root view controller after logging out?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uisplitviewcontroller

According to Apple, the split view should always be the root view controller throughout the life time of the app.

Anytime I log out of an account, the only way I was able to reload the detail view controller data was to make the log-in controller the root view controller if the user logged out, and then make the spit view the root view controller again.

This is just an example:

```
// if the user is not logged in
if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: LoginController())
    } else {
        // If the user is logged in, show the main controller
        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: MainController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout()))
    }
```

Without doing what I did above: If I were to log out, the log-in view would present itself modally. If I were to sign in to a different account and then dismiss the login controller modally, the split view would still look the same from the last account. So is there a method or a technique for me to present the log in controller with animation that, upon re-login, the split view updates? I want to make sure I follow the guidelines.

(Note: the root of the detail view controller in the split view is a UICollectionViewController. I'm doing all of this programmatically.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I normally have one rootViewController, that stays as a root forever.
Its purpose is to hold and present login and mainController.
This way you always have have a rootViewController, It gives dynamic of switching between presented controllers.

I personally prefer to re allocate login controller and main controller before presentation, to be sure no data is left from the last logged in user.

```
Example:

class rooViewController: UIViewController {

    func presentedLogin() {
        self.loginController = LoginController()
        self.mainController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) { 
            self.presentViewController(self.loginController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func presentMainApplication() {
        self.mainController = MainController()
        self.loginController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true) {
            self.presentViewController(self.mainController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


//App Delegate or any ether place of this application logic:

  if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid == nil {
            rootViewController.presentedLogin()
        } else {
            // If the user is logged in, show the main controller
            rootViewController.presentMainApplication()
        }
```

Comment: Would `self.mainController` be of type UINavigationController? As in, `var mainController: UINavigationController?`

Comment: Also, wouldn't it be advisable to have a singleton instance inside the rootViewController class?

Comment: First question: I prefer UIViewController, I do not see the benefit of UINavigationController for this purpose since it has to have a root view controller. But it is a personal decision that is based on my needs. Second question: Root controller is a single instance, but not a single tone, if that is what you mean. Is it?